# Determine if a language is regular or not. Don't know how to start to prove.

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

I'm trying to understand how to prove the following language:

> $$L= \{a^nx \mid n \geqslant 0 \text{ and } x \in \{a,b,c\}^*   \text{ and }  |x| = n + 1\}$$

In my opinion it's regular but I can't find a way to prove. I'm aware about the pumping lemma but I can't find a start point.

Comment: What are you familiar with in this field? Do you know what the pumping lemma is? Do you know how it is used to prove certain languages are not regular? (I haven't looked to see whether this language is regular, I'm just asking.)

Comment: @Brian Yep, I'm. But I was not able to figure out a start point to prove somehow.

Comment: OK. But you should at least edit your post to say that you're aware of the pumping lemma. In addition, look through examples of the use of the pumping lemma, and see if you can figure out whether they apply to your problem. If you think it does, but you're not sure, then say so. If you can't see how to apply the pumping lemma, then say so. Etc. Any information you can provide will make your question more attractive to answerers, and will avoid downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: @BrianTung I add a new information.

Comment: If you are a finite automaton and start reading a word of that language that has $n$ much larger that your memory, by the time you got to the end of the initial prefix of $a$ you've forgotten how many you've seen: you cannot then check that the rest is ok.

Comment: In this new edition, you made your question totally different (and nonsense). Please revert to the original question.

Comment: I just reverted your question to the original one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $L$ is regular. Since regular languages are closed under intersection, then so is
$$
L \cap a^*b^* = \{a^nb^{n+1}\mid n \geqslant 0\}
$$
Now, since you know about the pumping lemma, you should be able to conclude that this language is not regular.